# How is the special "note" box made in readthedocs.org?

Tags: css, python-sphinx

I am wondering how the special text box in [readthedocs.org](http://django-filer.readthedocs.org/en/1.0.0/) is made.

For instance in:

[image]

I think there is much more than tweaking the `css` file, and I would really like to create one on my own.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** I know the overall box comes from the `note` directive. However, my question is: how do they make this "!" mark? I cannot find the clue in the `css` file.

Comment: Why is this tagged Python?

Comment: @SiHa well, the render engine is written in python. I think it may have something to do with render engine and you can learn more about it [here](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/)

Comment: You're aware it is made with the Sphinx documentation tool and that you can see the [source of that page on github](https://github.com/divio/django-filer/blob/1.0.0/docs/index.rst)? It's made just with the `note` directive `.. note:: upgrading from...`. As mentioned in the footer, they have a customized css as well.

Comment: @OliverW. Yes. However, how do they make this cute "!" mark and I investigated in the css sheet but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an [FontAwesome icon](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/exclamation-circle/)

```css
div {
  background-color: skyblue;
  padding: 3px 10px;
}
.fa-exclamation-circle {
  color: white;
}
span {
  color: white;
  margin-left: 6px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div>
  <i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <span>Note</span>
</div>
```

Comment: It seems like they also implement `:before:` directive so that exclamation mark can be put in front of the text each time `note` directive is used? However, I'm not sure if this is true. Or it can be implemented in purely css? Thanks!